# How do I create a HIVE Metastore table parquet snappy files on s3?

Tags: hive, hiveql, parquet, trino, hive-metastore

I have a HIVE connector in Trino setup.. the files are in S3 and I can start to create tables to query data.. however I am getting an error.. and I suspect it could be the compression method.. is my `TABLE` creation step looking okay..

```
SELECT * from ibtickers;

Query 20220925_104301_00008_h8me8, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 3 total, 0 done (0.00%)
0.15 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20220925_104301_00008_h8me8 failed: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://MYBUCKET/data_dump/ib_tickers/20220918_192603-092364.snappy.parquet
```

here is the lines I used to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive.<MY_SCHEMA>.<MY_TABLE> (
              ->   column_one       VARCHAR,
              ->   column_two       VARCHAR,
              ->   column_three     VARCHAR,
              ->   column_four      DOUBLE,
              ->   column_five      VARCHAR,
              ->   column_six       VARCHAR,
              ->   query_start_time TIMESTAMP)
              -> WITH (
              ->   external_location = 's3a://<MY_S3_BUCKET_NAME>/dir_one/dir_two',
              ->   format = 'PARQUET'
              -> );
```

The files work locally when I am utilizing a viewer in pycharm just fine so.. my guess is my TRINO or HIVE setup needs fixing..?

## EDIT

I just tried the other compression types from meltano.. and none seem to work.. I've already confirmed the s3 files are reachable and downloadable via boto3 ... so this leads me to think this has to do with how I create the tables.. so any help here is appreciated.

I found the fuller stack trace and it looks like i need to just.. figure out how to add the compression support to ...HIVE Metastore?

## Querying parquet that's GZip error

```
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://test-bucket-13549875235/data_dump/ib_tickers_gzip/20220925_173820-404835.gz.parquet
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource.handleException(ParquetPageSource.java:169)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createPageSource$6(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:271)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:75)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292)
    at io.trino.spi.Page.getLoadedPage(Page.java:229)
    at io.trino.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:411)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$10(Driver.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:706)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:306)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:277)
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:736)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:164)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:515)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_397____20220925_161652_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.trino.spi.type.DoubleType
    at io.trino.spi.type.AbstractType.writeLong(AbstractType.java:91)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.LongColumnReader.readValue(LongColumnReader.java:31)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.lambda$readValues$2(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:248)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.processValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:304)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:246)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readPrimitive(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:235)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:441)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:540)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:523)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.lambda$nextPage$3(ParquetReader.java:272)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:72)
    ... 17 more
```

## Querying parquet that's zstd compressed error

```
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://test-bucket-13549875235/data_dump/ib_tickers_zstd/20220925_175330-188177.zstd.parquet
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource.handleException(ParquetPageSource.java:169)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createPageSource$6(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:271)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:75)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292)
    at io.trino.spi.Page.getLoadedPage(Page.java:229)
    at io.trino.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:411)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$10(Driver.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:706)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:306)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:277)
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:736)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:164)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:515)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_397____20220925_161652_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.trino.spi.type.DoubleType
    at io.trino.spi.type.AbstractType.writeLong(AbstractType.java:91)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.LongColumnReader.readValue(LongColumnReader.java:31)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.lambda$readValues$2(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:248)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.processValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:304)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:246)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readPrimitive(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:235)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:441)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:540)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:523)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.lambda$nextPage$3(ParquetReader.java:272)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:72)
    ... 17 more
```

## Querying parquet that's brotli compressed error

```
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://test-bucket-13549875235/data_dump/ib_tickers_br/20220925_181026-076690.br.parquet
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource.handleException(ParquetPageSource.java:169)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createPageSource$6(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:271)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:75)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292)
    at io.trino.spi.Page.getLoadedPage(Page.java:223)
    at io.trino.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:411)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$10(Driver.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:706)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:306)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:277)
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:736)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:164)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:515)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_397____20220925_161652_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading dictionary page
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PageReader.readDictionaryPage(PageReader.java:118)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.setPageReader(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:188)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:439)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:540)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:523)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.lambda$nextPage$3(ParquetReader.java:272)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:72)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: io.trino.parquet.ParquetCorruptionException: Codec not supported in Parquet: BROTLI
    at io.trino.parquet.ParquetCompressionUtils.decompress(ParquetCompressionUtils.java:69)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PageReader.readDictionaryPage(PageReader.java:113)
    ... 23 more
```

## Querying parquet that's snappy compressed error

```
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Failed to read Parquet file: s3a://test-bucket-13549875235/data_dump/ib_tickers_snappy/20220918_194105-135895.snappy.parquet
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource.handleException(ParquetPageSource.java:169)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createPageSource$6(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:271)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:75)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385)
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292)
    at io.trino.spi.Page.getLoadedPage(Page.java:229)
    at io.trino.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:411)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$10(Driver.java:314)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:706)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:306)
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:277)
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:736)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:164)
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:515)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_397____20220925_161652_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.trino.spi.type.DoubleType
    at io.trino.spi.type.AbstractType.writeLong(AbstractType.java:91)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.LongColumnReader.readValue(LongColumnReader.java:31)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.lambda$readValues$2(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:248)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.processValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:304)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readValues(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:246)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.PrimitiveColumnReader.readPrimitive(PrimitiveColumnReader.java:235)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:441)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:540)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:523)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.lambda$nextPage$3(ParquetReader.java:272)
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:72)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the `LONG` in a parquet file doesn't convert to `DOUBLE` but to `BIGINT` when using HIVE.. this allowed me to proceed to take in the offending column

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive.<MY_SCHEMA>.<MY_TABLE> (
              ->   column_one       VARCHAR,
              ->   column_two       VARCHAR,
              ->   column_three     VARCHAR,
              ->   column_four      BIGINT,     <--- change this
              ->   column_five      VARCHAR,
              ->   column_six       VARCHAR)
              -> WITH (
              ->   external_location = 's3a://<MY_S3_BUCKET_NAME>/dir_one/dir_two',
              ->   format = 'PARQUET'
              -> );
```